# Equality of pandas data frames except dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I need to check if two DataFrames are somewhat "equal", but in a looser sense than [`pandas.DataFrame.equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) is implementing it currently.

I am aware of `pandas.testing.assert_frames_equal` and I really love it, but now I need it a control flow statement and not for testing. For instance I'd like the following code snippet to output `equal`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1.0]])

if frames_equals(df1, df2, check_dtypes=False):
    print("equal")
else:
    print("not equal")
```

Is there such a function readily available in the pandas library?

**Note:** The question is not about how to build one, but rather if there **already is** one.

Comment: Looser *how*?  What does `DataFrame.equals` check that you don't want it to?

Comment: Can you give a *minimal* example of 2 dataframes which you want to be equal (but which aren't by `pd.DataFrame.equals`) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated my question and added a little note.

Comment: Does assert_frame_equal with `check_dtype=False` not work? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html

Comment: `assert_frame_equal` doesn't have a return value, so I can't use it in if statements